Firebase Phone Auth SMS Delay
Today when using the SMS 6-digit verification code feature of firebase phone auth, the SMS got delivered 10, 15 minutes after the request.
Is this normal? Or was this a very rare exception?
I expected the SMS to be delivered with a maximum delay of 2-3 minutes.
I've been experimenting ever since this happened, and didn't get that big of a delay later.
I am on the cusp of releasing my app, and this delay worries me to the point of removing phone auth all together from my app.
